Getting GRIB data of particular region by bounding box in GeoServer
We have a web app that shows maps we want to show some ocean effects on the map the UI and animation part have been sorted out but the problem we are facing now is the data is in GRIB format and it is a huge file (around 1 GB) so obviously we cannot load it in the browser in one go.
Someone suggested that geoserver has a plugin (https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/grib/grib.html) I have installed it but it seems to give a colored map based on the intensity of the oceanic data parameter but what we want is instead an array of values based on the bounding box the user is currently viewing. We are using Geoserver as a backend and leaflet for rendering the map.
Basically, we need the values for only a region, not the entire globe, we can provide the bounding box coordinates from the Leaflet but how to use them in GeoServer to get an array of numbers is something I am not sure about.

It sounds like you are requesting a WMS image when you want to get the data which would be a WCS request, I'm not sure if leaflet supports that
